# two actionCommand at the same time?

Tags: java, user-interface, interface, action

I have three `JRadioButtons` and 1 `JButton`. I'm having problem for my `actionCommand`.

When the user chose one of the `JRadioButton` (monthly, bi-weekly, weekly), and also clicked the `JButton` (Calculate), then starts the `actionCommand` if loop but I'm not sure how to do that.

Also the `textArea` didn't get displayed properly.

```
package Lab4;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BalanceCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_DIGITS = 30;
    private JTextField monthlyPayments;
    private JTextField principalValue;
    private JTextField annualInterestRate;
    private JTextArea output;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        BalanceCalculator aCalculator = new BalanceCalculator();
        aCalculator.setVisible(true);
    }

    public BalanceCalculator()
    {
        super("Mortgage Calculator");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(700, 500);
        pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (13, 2, 2, 2));

        JPanel textPanel1 = new JPanel();
        textPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter the number of payments: ");
        textPanel1.add(label1);
        pane.add(textPanel1);

        monthlyPayments = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS);
        textPanel1.add(monthlyPayments);
        pane.add(textPanel1);

        JPanel jRadiobuttonPanel = new JPanel();
        jRadiobuttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JRadioButton monthlyButton = new JRadioButton ("Pay by monthly");
        monthlyButton.addActionListener(this);
        jRadiobuttonPanel.add(monthlyButton);
        pane.add(jRadiobuttonPanel);

        JRadioButton biweeklyButton = new JRadioButton ("Pay by bi-weekly");
        biweeklyButton.addActionListener(this);
        jRadiobuttonPanel.add(biweeklyButton);
        pane.add(jRadiobuttonPanel);

        JRadioButton weeklyButton = new JRadioButton ("Pay by weekly");
        weeklyButton.addActionListener(this);
        jRadiobuttonPanel.add(weeklyButton);
        pane.add(jRadiobuttonPanel);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(monthlyButton); 
        group.add(biweeklyButton);
        group.add(weeklyButton);
        monthlyButton.setSelected (true);

        JPanel textPanel2 = new JPanel();
        textPanel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter the principal: ");
        textPanel2.add(label2);
        pane.add(textPanel2);

        principalValue = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS);
        textPanel2.add(principalValue);
        pane.add(textPanel2);

        JPanel textPanel3 = new JPanel();
        textPanel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
        textPanel3.add(label3);
        pane.add(textPanel3);

        annualInterestRate = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS);
        textPanel3.add(annualInterestRate);
        pane.add(textPanel3);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JButton calculateButton = new JButton ("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(calculateButton);
        pane.add(buttonPanel);

        JLabel outputs = new JLabel("Data for your mortgage: ");
        pane.add(outputs);

        JPanel results = new JPanel();
        output = new JTextArea(200, 300);
        output.setLineWrap(true); 
        output.setEditable(false); 
        output.setVisible(true);
        results.add(output);
        pane.add(results);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton ("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(resetButton);
        pane.add(buttonPanel);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            assumingCorrectNumberFormats(e);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e2)
        {
            monthlyPayments.setText("Error: Re-enter number please.");
        }
    }

    public void assumingCorrectNumberFormats (ActionEvent e)
    {
        monthlyPayments.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You entered: " + e.getActionCommand ());
            }
         });

        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        while (actionCommand.equals("Calculate"))
        {
            if (actionCommand.equals("Pay by monthly"))
            {
                output.setText(toString());
            }

            else if (actionCommand.equals("Pay by bi-weekly"))
            {
                output.setText(toString());
            }

            else if (actionCommand.equals("Pay by weekly"))
            {
                output.setText(toString());
            }

            else if (actionCommand.equals("Reset"))
            {
                monthlyPayments.setText("");
                principalValue.setText("");
                annualInterestRate.setText("");
                output.setText("");
            }

            else
            {
                //enterYourNumber.setText("Unexpected error.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer always use the inner classes for adding function to the particular button one by one. I modified the code. Hope you will find it helpfully.....Though i don't have more reputation i couldn't ask any question in the comments. Sorry about that.

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class BalanceCalculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
    {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_DIGITS = 30;
    private JTextField monthlyPayments;
    private JTextField principalValue;
    private JTextField annualInterestRate;
    private JTextArea output;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        BalanceCalculator aCalculator = new BalanceCalculator();
        aCalculator.setVisible(true);
    }

    public BalanceCalculator()
    {
        super("Mortgage Calculator");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(700, 500);
        pane.setLayout (new GridLayout (13, 2, 2, 2));

        JPanel textPanel1 = new JPanel();
        textPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter the number of payments: ");
        textPanel1.add(label1);
        pane.add(textPanel1);

        monthlyPayments = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS);
        textPanel1.add(monthlyPayments);
        pane.add(textPanel1);

        JPanel jRadiobuttonPanel = new JPanel();
        jRadiobuttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        final JRadioButton monthlyButton = new JRadioButton ("Pay by monthly");
        monthlyButton.addActionListener(this);
        jRadiobuttonPanel.add(monthlyButton);
        pane.add(jRadiobuttonPanel);

        final JRadioButton biweeklyButton = new JRadioButton ("Pay by bi-weekly");
        biweeklyButton.addActionListener(this);
        jRadiobuttonPanel.add(biweeklyButton);
        pane.add(jRadiobuttonPanel);

        final JRadioButton weeklyButton = new JRadioButton ("Pay by weekly");
        weeklyButton.addActionListener(this);
        jRadiobuttonPanel.add(weeklyButton);
        pane.add(jRadiobuttonPanel);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(monthlyButton); 
        group.add(biweeklyButton);
        group.add(weeklyButton);
        monthlyButton.setSelected (true);

        JPanel textPanel2 = new JPanel();
        textPanel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Enter the principal: ");
        textPanel2.add(label2);
        pane.add(textPanel2);

        principalValue = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS);
        textPanel2.add(principalValue);
        pane.add(textPanel2);

        JPanel textPanel3 = new JPanel();
        textPanel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Enter the annual interest rate: ");
        textPanel3.add(label3);
        pane.add(textPanel3);

        annualInterestRate = new JTextField(NUMBER_OF_DIGITS);
        textPanel3.add(annualInterestRate);
        pane.add(textPanel3);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

        JButton calculateButton = new JButton ("Calculate");
        calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                    if (monthlyButton.isSelected())
            {

                output.setText("Monthly Button");
            }

            else if (weeklyButton.isSelected())
            {
                output.setText("Weekly Button");
            }

            else if (biweeklyButton.isSelected())
            {
                output.setText("Bi weeklybutton");
            }

            else if (monthlyButton.isSelected())
            {
                monthlyPayments.setText("");
                principalValue.setText("");
                annualInterestRate.setText("");
                output.setText("");
            }

            else
            {
                //enterYourNumber.setText("Unexpected error.");
            }
                }

        });
        buttonPanel.add(calculateButton);
        pane.add(buttonPanel);

        JLabel outputs = new JLabel("Data for your mortgage: ");
        pane.add(outputs);

        JPanel results = new JPanel();
        output = new JTextArea(200, 300);
        output.setLineWrap(true); 
        output.setEditable(false); 
        output.setVisible(true);
        results.add(output);
        pane.add(results);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton ("Reset");
        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                    monthlyPayments.setText(null);  
                    principalValue.setText(null);
                    annualInterestRate.setText(null);
                }

        });
        buttonPanel.add(resetButton);
        pane.add(buttonPanel);

        add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        try
        {
            assumingCorrectNumberFormats(e);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e2)
        {
            monthlyPayments.setText("Error: Re-enter number please.");
        }
    }

    public void assumingCorrectNumberFormats (ActionEvent e)
    {
        monthlyPayments.addActionListener (new ActionListener ()
        {
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("You entered: " + e.getActionCommand ());
            }
        }
                );


        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        while (actionCommand.equals("Calculate"))
        {

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: I added more JRadioButtons,would this work?`code`calculateButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (monthlyButton.isSelected())
        {

   if (compoundDailyButton.isSelected())
   {
    output.setText("hi");
   }
   else if (compoundWeeklyButton.isSelected())
   {
    output.setText("hi2");
   }
   else if (compoundMonthlyButton.isSelected())
   {
    output.setText("hi3");
   }
   else if (compoundSemiannuallyButton.isSelected())
   {
    
   }
   else if (compoundAnnuallyButton.isSelected())
   {
    
   }
        }`

Comment: It should be work. Put same codings to all radio buttons action performed method.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in assumingCorrectNumberFormats() method is incorrect,you are uisng while loop to check for button click and inside the while loop you are checking for the radio buttons click events.You need to separate checks for radio button and button.Something like:

```
public void assumingCorrectNumberFormats(ActionEvent e) {

        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        if (actionCommand.equals("Calculate")) {
            System.out.println("inside calculate");
            String strPrincipal = principalValue.getText();
            String strAnnualInterest = annualInterestRate.getText();
            // do calculation
            Integer result = Integer.parseInt(strPrincipal) * Integer.parseInt(strAnnualInterest);
            System.out.println("result=" + result);
            // set the result
            output.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
        if (actionCommand.equals("Pay by monthly")) {
            output.setText(toString());
        }
        else if (actionCommand.equals("Pay by bi-weekly")) {
            output.setText(toString());
        }
        else if (actionCommand.equals("Pay by weekly")) {
            output.setText(toString());
        }
        else if (actionCommand.equals("Reset")) {
            monthlyPayments.setText("");
            principalValue.setText("");
            annualInterestRate.setText("");
            output.setText("");
        }
    }
```

You can add separate conditions for new RadioButtons.
Also reduce the number of rows in JtextArea,else change the LayoutManager accordingly.

```
output = new JTextArea(200, 60);
```